# Correção código portugol

Tags: portugol

Meu código não esta fazendo as contas

```
programa
{
    
    funcao inicio()
    {
    real n1, n2, n3, n4 ,n5
    escreva("\nQual a população da cidade de 1 até 20000 habitantes: ")
    leia(n1)
    se (n1 > 1 e n1 < 5001)
    n1 = 300000 * 1.5
    escreva("\nA Verba dessa cidade é: R$", n1)
    leia (n2)
    senao se (n2 > 5001 e n2 < 8000 )
    n2 = 600000 * 1.0
    escreva("\nA Verba dessa cidade é: R$", n2)
    leia (n3)
    senao se (n3 > 8001 e n3 < 12000 )
    n2 = 1000000 * 1.0
    escreva("\nA Verba dessa cidade é: R$", n3)
    leia (n4)
    senao se (n4 > 12001 e n4 < 20000 )
    n2 = 2500000 * 1.0
    escreva("\nA Verba dessa cidade é: R$", n4)
    leia (n5)
    senao se (n5 > 20000)
    n2 = 5000000 * 1.5
    escreva("\nA Verba dessa cidade é: R$", n5)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você esqueceu de abrir chaves depois das condições. Também só é necessário ler a variável `n1` uma só vez ao invés de ler várias vezes e atribuir o valor em uma variável diferente.

Ficaria assim seu código:

```
programa {
    funcao inicio() {
        real n1
        escreva("\nQual a população da cidade de 1 até 20000 habitantes: ")
        leia(n1)
        se (n1 > 1 e n1 < 5001)
        {
            n1 = 300000 * 1.5
            escreva("\nA Verba dessa cidade é: R$", n1)
        }
        senao se (n1 >= 5001 e n1 < 8000 )
        {
            n1 = 600000 * 1.0
            escreva("\nA Verba dessa cidade é: R$", n1)
        }
        senao se (n1 >= 8001 e n1 < 12000 )
        {
            n1 = 1000000 * 1.0
            escreva("\nA Verba dessa cidade é: R$", n1)
        }
        senao se (n1 > 12001 e n1 < 20000 )
        {
            n1 = 2500000 * 1.0
            escreva("\nA Verba dessa cidade é: R$", n1)
        }
        senao se (n1 >= 20000)
        {
            n1 = 5000000 * 1.5
            escreva("\nA Verba dessa cidade é: R$", n1)
        }
    }
}
```